# AWS - Mysfits, unable to create authorizer during import-rest-api

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

I started over from the first module but on Module 4, I put this command in:

```sh
aws apigateway import-rest-api \
  --parameters endpointConfigurationTypes=REGIONAL \
  --body file://~/environment/aws-modern-application-workshop/module-4/aws-cli/api-swagger.json \
  --fail-on-warnings
```

And I get this back:

> An error occurred (BadRequestException) when calling the ImportRestApi operation: Errors found during import:
>           Unable to create authorizer 'MysfitsUserPoolAuthorizer': ProviderARNs need to be valid Cognito Userpools. Invalid ARNs-
>   arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-2:mShannon:userpool/us-east-2_Hnn2pbgZC

What am I doing wrong? What other steps can I try?

Comment: What is the content of JSON specified in awscli call?

Comment: ```    "securityDefinitions": {
        "MysfitsUserPoolAuthorizer": {
            "type": "apiKey",
            "name": "Authorization",
            "in": "header",
            "x-amazon-apigateway-authtype": "cognito_user_pools",
            "x-amazon-apigateway-authorizer": {
                "type": "COGNITO_USER_POOLS",
                "providerARNs": [
                    "arn:aws:cognito-idp:us-east-2:mShannon:userpool/us-east-2_Hnn2pbgZC"
                ]
            }
        }
   ```